# Div not reaching edge of webpage in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, web-testing

[white space between green div and both top and sides of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEeOx.png)

My index page

```
export default function Home()
{
    return(
        <div className = {stylesMain.bodyDiv}> 
            <div>home</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the css it's calling

```
.bodyDiv{   
    background-color: green;
    height:500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: 'fixed';
    display: 'flex';
    justify-content: 'center';
    align-items: 'center'; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
}
```

As the image shows, the div is not reaching the edge of the page

I first tried to find solutions online, but none of the solutions were working for me.
One solution in particular popped up multiple times which was to make a  and set its margin and padding to 0 but whenever I try to use a body tag

```
export default function Home()
{
    return(

        <body>
        <div className = {stylesMain.bodyDiv}> 
            <div>home</div>
        </div>
        </body>
            
    )
}
```

it throws this error:
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a `CSS` issue. You just need to add `0` margins to all elements in you styling. Try adding in your `style.css` file the following and it should do the trick. Hope that helps.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

`margin` property will remove all margins by default unless you specifically set margin to an element.

`padding` will do the same for padding of the elements,

`box-sizing` allows to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height. If you set `box-sizing: border-box;` on an element, padding and border are included in the width and height.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Though your suggestion did not directly solve the issue, it pointed me  in the right direction and I have it fixed now. Since I was using module css files the * threw an error but after some research on that I found I needed to create a global css file and use _app.js as the main page so I could import that global css